# WordPress Update 5.0.2 broke the WooCommerce Orders tab (All)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I have updated my website to version 5.0.2 and the Orders tab (only the All tab) is not showing any orders. The other tabs were working fine before the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Fix before new Update. Add that code in child or parent theme `functions.php` file

```
function woocommerce_query_request( $queryArgs ) {
    if ( isset( $queryArgs['post_status'] ) && empty( $queryArgs['post_status'] ) ) {
        unset( $queryArgs['post_status'] );
    }
    return $queryArgs;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'woocommerce_query_request', 1, 1 );
```